# How do I design a peer-to-peer app that avoids using listening sockets?

Tags: sockets, networking

I've noticed that if you want to write an application that utilizes listening sockets, you need to create port forwarding rules on your router. If I want to connect two computers without either one of the the computers messing about with router settings, is there a way that I can get the two clients to connect to each other without either of them using listening sockets? There would need to be another server somewhere else telling them to connect but is it possible?

Comment: Forwarding rules are only needed if the computer with the serversocket is behind a firewall.  If both computers are on the same LAN, or just separated by regular routers it's not necessary to reprogram the routers.  Do you want your program to work across the internet, or only on a local network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some clarifications, and an answer:

1. Routers don't care about, or handle ports, that is the role of a firewall, which do port forwarding. The router/firewall combined device most of us have at home adds to the common misunderstanding.
2. Can you connect two computers without ServerSocket? No. You can use UDP (a stateless, connectionless communication protocol), but the role of a ServerSocket is to "listen" for incoming connection requests, and generate a Socket from those requests, which creates a communications channel between two endpoints. A Socket has both an InputStream and an OutputStream, so it can both read at write at either end. At that point (once the connection is made), the distinction between client/server is arbitrary, since a Socket is a two-way connection object, which allows both sides to send/receive.
3. What about proxying? Doesn't that allow connections between two computers without a ServerSocket? Well, no, because the server that's doing the proxying still has to be using a ServerSocket. Depending on what application you're trying to implement, this might be the way to go, or or might just add overhead. Even if there were "another server somewhere else telling them to connect", somebody has to listen for a connection request, which is the job of the ServerSocket.
4. If connections are happening over already open ports (most publicly accessible servers have ports <1024 not blocked by firewalls, but exceptions exist), then you shouldn't need to change firewall settings to get the connection to work.

So, to reiterate, the ONLY role of a ServerSocket (as far as your question is concerned) is to listen for incoming connection requests, and from those requests, create a Socket, which is a two-way communications channel between the two end points.

To answer the question, "How do I design a peer-to-peer app that avoids using listening sockets?", you don't. In the case of something like Vuze, the software acts as both client and server simultaneously, hence the term "peer", vs. "client" or "server" alone. In Vuze every client is a server, and every server (except for the tracker) is a client.

Comment: The title of the post is one I wrote, based on what I understood of the question. The OP's title was "ServerSocket vs Socket Java", which doesn't ask anything in particular. :-P

Answer (score 2):

If you need a TCP connection between the 2 computers and both of them are behind routers (and you don't want to set up port forwarding) I think the only other possibility you have is having a third server somewhere that isn't behind a firewall running a ServerSocket and accepting connections between your 2 other computers and proxying communications between the 2. You can't establish a TCP Connection between the 2 without one listening to a socket and the other connecting to it.

Comment: @Tyler Petrochko: This technic is called "server relay". Take a look on the web, internet is full of explanation

Comment: @Jon Well, there's also [TCP hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching).

Answer (score 0):

> Q: If I want to connect two computers without either one of the the
>   computers messing about with router settings, is there a way that I
>   can get the two clients to connect to each other

Yes: have the server listen on an open port :)